# What could be the different approach for web based and windows based product testing?

Tags: asp.net, testing, web, window

If i am testing windows based project and my documentation is according to windows based and suddenly i have to migrate my windows based project into web based project according to need.
What different approach should i follow if i have all the documentation and test strategy for windows based project ?
**Is there any change in test cases and test strategy?**
Can i have few suggestion regarding this, what should i change and what different approach i need to bring in my testing.
I am changing my windows based project **online examination** into web based project.

Comment: This question is very general and doesn't fit in well with the SO question model. You might have a hard time getting many responses if you don't make your question more specific by giving an example of something you've tried, why it doesn't work, and specifically what you need help doing.

Comment: Thanks for your response i would keep your point in mind and next time i would try to explain with example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some suggestion.
Well U have to perform Usability testing, Security testing , Browser compatibility testing.
U have to also check temporary data storage whenever your site lost connection with server.

Comment: @vekvijay-thanks for your early reply , can you explain my other mentioned points too?  Thanks

Comment: Well, You have to create new test cases for Security & Browser compatibility testing and Update Usability testing. and U have to perform performance testing also because so many people are giving online exam same time.

Comment: @vek- Thanks for your suggestion and i have found your suggestion helping. Cross compatibility testing and test cases regarding this must be helping for me. Even i can test it on same browser with different version of browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Perform load testing on your application and security testing. Also test this on mobile browsers.